# SelectedIndexChanged EventOutOfRange Exception when clicking datagridview headers in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am having an issue with my dataGridView that causes an EventOutOfRange Exception error when the column headers of the view are clicked. I understand why the error is happening, I am just having an issue creating a work around. Is there a way I can create an if statement that looks to see if the selected index is -1? Everything I have tried is invalid.

```
    private void student_grid_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView theGrid = sender as DataGridView;
        if (theGrid != null)
        {
            //The line below is what causes the error.
            DataGridViewRow row = theGrid.SelectedRows[0];
            stuinfo_fill.Text = row.Cells["Student ID"].Value.ToString();    
        }
        if (stuinfo_fill.Text == String.Empty)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You must have a student selected.");
        }
        else
        {
            PhysicianFill(stuinfo_fill.Text);
            StudentInfo(stuinfo_fill.Text);
            sch_rad.Checked = false;
            newsch_btn.Enabled = true;
            schList_btn.Enabled = true;
            phynew_btn.Enabled = true;
            phylist_btn.Enabled = true;

        }
    }
```

Comment: _if (theGrid != null && theGrid.SelectedRows != null)_

Comment: Both conditions are met and the error still happens. Is there a way to do && theGrid.SelectedRows != -1). I get an error when i do that.

Comment: Add also a check on _if(.. && theGrid.SelectedRows.Count > 0)_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this can help

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DatagridView_45493968
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        BindingList<dgventry> dgvItemList = new BindingList<dgventry>();
        DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
        TextBox txtb = new TextBox();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //Nothing in the wysiwyg form, everything in codeBehind
            MakeTheGrid();
            MakeTheTextBox();
            /**/

            //add some records to the Grid
            dgvItemList.Add(new dgventry { col1 = "1", col2 = "11", col3 = "111" });
            dgvItemList.Add(new dgventry { col1 = "2", col2 = "22", col3 = "222" });
            dgvItemList.Add(new dgventry { col1 = "3", col2 = "22", col3 = "333" });


        }

        private void Dgv_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridView theGrid = sender as DataGridView;

            //if the grid aint null, and the grid has rows, and something is selected
            if (theGrid != null && theGrid.RowCount > 0 && theGrid.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
            {
                //get the `OwningRow` of the selected Cells and do your thing!
                txtb.Text = (string)theGrid.SelectedCells[0].OwningRow.Cells[0].FormattedValue;
            }
        }

        private void MakeTheTextBox()
        {
            txtb.Location = new Point(dgv.Location.X, dgv.Location.Y + dgv.Height + 5);
            this.Controls.Add(txtb);
        }

        private void MakeTheGrid()
        {
            dgv.Location = new Point(this.Location.X + 5, this.Location.Y + 5);
            dgv.DataSource = dgvItemList;
            this.Controls.Add(dgv);
            dgv.SelectionChanged += Dgv_SelectionChanged;
        }
    }

    public class dgventry
    {
        public string col1 { get; set; }
        public string col2 { get; set; }
        public string col3 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped solve the issue. I appreciate it.